# Unit testing field validation with MockMvc but without Spring context?

Tags: validation, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible to test `@Valid` annotations using `MockMvc` and `MockitoJUnitRunner`? I can test most of the behavior of my CRUD controller but validation seems to require the use of Spring's JUnit runner, building the entire context and creating the JPA repo implementation which requires a lot of stuff.

The test below tries to test a POST method receiving a `Customer` entity where the `firstName` field is annotated with `@Size(min=2, max=20)`. The result is

```
java.lang.AssertionError: View name expected:<edit> but was:<redirect:/info>
```

So the validation did not run.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DataControllerTest {
    @Mock
    CustomerRepository mockRepo;

    @InjectMocks
    private DataController controller;

    MockMvc mockmvc;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockmvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBadSubmit() throws Exception {
        mockmvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/edit/1")
            .param("firstName", "a"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.view().name("edit"));
        Mockito.verifyZeroInteractions(mockRepo);
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class DataController {
    @Autowired
    public CustomerRepository crep;

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/edit/{id}"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(Model model, @Valid Customer customer, Errors result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "edit";
        }
        crep.save(customer);
        return "redirect:/info";
    }
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id = null;

    @Column(length=20)
    @Size(min=2, max=20)
    private String firstName;
    ...
}
```

JPA Repository interface:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    List<Customer> findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` is to automatically load the application context and wire up everything automatically. You should be able to use `MockitoJUnitRunner` but you'll have to load the application context you want to use manually in your test. Regardless, however, you do need to load an application context, because calling `DataController#add()` through Spring is the only way that the `@Valid` annotation will be processed.

EDIT: If the real problem here is loading the JPA repository, you can use `MockitoJUnitRunner` and just load a test application context where a mock JPA repository is manually wired in, at little to no expense.

Comment: I'm not sure how to create an application context that processes the `@Valid` annotations but does not complain about the missing JPA repository bean, unless I set `@Autowired(required=false)`.

Comment: The `@Valid` annotation will be tested so long as the enclosing class is wired up to the test class or is retrieved by the test class from the application context. Let me know if you need some example code.

Comment: If it's not a big problem, please do give an example.